# Custom component with scaffolding actions for styles and scripts

Tags: sxa

I try to develop a SXA custom module. This module should also have custom styles and/or scripts.

- The scripts and styles should work site- independent.
- The scripts and styles should only be available when the module is used within a site.

Which scaffolding actions are necessary for registering the scripts or styles.

[image]

The "Edit Editing Theme" extends only the experience editor style and I dont know what the "Edit Site Theme" does.

How should the necessary items are stored in the media library/feature folder? 
[image]

Thanks a lot
Uwe

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there. I would indeed store the CSS and JS files in a seperate theme that has nothing other then the files needed to run your module. Personally I would store the theme in the feature folder, just as you did in the screenshot

For the scaffolding part you can use the action "Edit Site Theme" to add your theme as a base theme to the current theme used on the site.

Comment: Hey Mark, it works! I think, I'll write a detailed answer. Thanks